# What’s the true meaning of this.dummyproperty = dummyproperty?

Tags: javascript, function, this, frontend

I tried to look for this answer anywhere but somehow I did not manage to find it.
Basically why and for which practical reasons I see many times (especially in React tutorials) this code:

```
const apple = function() {
      this.juice = juice
}
```

1) Is it to link the value (scope) of 'this' to the juice property (from the window object)? 
2) If yes, should not it be already referring to 'juice' since it is not an arrow function? 
3) Is it producing some effect if parameters are passed into the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the **function constructor pattern**, it's used to **create objects**.

```js
   
const Juice = function(juice) {
      this.juice = juice;
}
const appleJuice = new Juice('apple');
console.log(appleJuice.juice); // apple

const orangeJuice = new Juice('orange');
console.log(orangeJuice.juice); // orange
```

In resume, you use a function constructor to create a **new object with the value of this pointing to the newly created object**.
You can create several instances of the object (appleJuice, orangeJuice), but each instance can have it's own property values (apple, or orange)

Check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp)

Comment: To add to this answer, if you call the function without `new` it executes the function in its scope. So if you didn't pass the `juice` argument in, the function would look in the outer scope for the variable named `juice`. If it didn't exist, then an error would be thrown.

Comment: so for each property added to the contructor I would need to set, e.g., this.size=size, this.sweet=sweet etc.?

Comment: @Enrico Yes, you should pass `size` as a param, then do `this.size = size`. Finally, you could access `yourObjectName.size`